# Spark Streaming Notebook for x hours

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I created a Notebook in Databricks (Azure) that stream data directly into our Datawarehouse.
I would like to schedule this ro run every day from (exam) 2AM till 10PM, in the off period some maintenance would run.
I can schedule this to start every day at 2AM, but how could I make it nicely stop every day at arround 10PM ?